# Append Query String to URL with Jquery

Tags: jquery

What am I doing wrong?

1. Only on pages with the URL location of "/MyWebsite/Example.aspx" append "?template=PW"
2. But only to links that contain "/HelloWorld/default.aspx"

There is no ID or classes associated to this link, so I have to look for the URL.

This is my code, but the links are not updating.. I know I'm close!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (document.location.href.indexOf('/MyWebsite/Example.aspx') > 0)  
        {
            $('a[href*="/HelloWorld/default.aspx"]').append("href",$("?template=PW"))
        }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (document.location.href.indexOf('/MyWebsite/Example.aspx') > 0)  
        {
            var $el = $('a[href*="/HelloWorld/default.aspx"]');
            $el.attr("href", $el.attr("href")+ "?template=PW");
        }
});
```

Comment: I'd like to accomplish the same things but with all href how can I do that? please mention me @Shaz3e on twitter with your reply.

Comment: @shaz3e, use $.each method to loop all anchors, 
`$("a").each(function() {
   $(this).attr("href", $(this).attr("href")+ "?template=PW");
});`

Comment: I have already achieved this by using the following code.

<script type="text/javascript">
 var querystring = 'MyString'; // Replace this
 $('a').each(function(){
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  href += (href.match(/\?/) ? '&' : '#') + querystring;
  $(this).attr('href', href);
 });
</script>

Answer (score 3):

Use $.attr() to edit an attribute.

$.append() is used to insert an html child node inside your element.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (document.location.href.indexOf('/MyWebsite/Example.aspx') > 0)  
        {
            var href = '/HelloWorld/default.aspx';
            $('a[href*="' + href + '"]').attr("href", href + "?template=PW")
        }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This would definitely solve your problem as it did mine.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var querystring = 'MyString'; // Replace this
    $('a').each(function(){
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        href += (href.match(/\?/) ? '&' : '?') + querystring;
        $(this).attr('href', href);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
$('a[href*="/HelloWorld/default.aspx"]').append("href",$("?template=PW"))
```

With

```
$.each(
    $('a[href*="/HelloWorld/default.aspx"]'),
    function(index, value) {
        $(value).attr('href', $(value).attr('href') + '?template=PW');
    }
);
```

That will get you started, but you should also check to make sure there isn't a query string parameter already in the matched URL.

`$().append()` doesn't alter the value of the href attribute, it is used to insert content at the end of each matched element.  The [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/append/) has examples of how to use `$().append()`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you consider using [PURL](https://github.com/allmarkedup/purl)? With  PURL I was able to do this:

```
var url = "http://localhost/some/url?item1=one&item2=two";
if ($.url(url).attr('query')) {
    url = url + '&newItem=new';
}
else {
    url = url + '?newItem=new';
}
```